# Can I use "with respect to" on a certificate of appreciation?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice, translation

I'm translating a Persian gratitude certificate (like the ones in [this Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=appreciation%20certificate&client=ms-android-samsung&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijhO280eDVAhUDZFAKHf49ARQQ_AUICSgB&biw=360&bih=560)) and there is a statement at the beginning giving respects to the person. It would be **"with respects/regards to Ms. (Name)"** in word by word translating.

The sentence is respecting someone for her great sense of responsibility, so can I say "respectfully presented for your great sense of responsibility"?

As I noticed "with respect to" means "being related to something" or "concerning to", I want to make sure if it's possible I use this phrase to show only respects, and if not what are the alternatives?

Comment: If the sentence is something like " .. presented with respect to Ms. .." you could render that as " .. respectfully presented to Ms. ...".  How exact do you need the translation to be. The phrase “with respect to” is a standard idiom and it loses its idiomatic meaning it you break it up with an adjective (eg. “with our deepest respect” or “with much-deserved respect”)

Comment: The sentence is  some how respecting some one for her great sense of responsibilty, so can I say "respectfully peresented for your great sense of responsibilty"?

Comment: Or can I say "with do respect for your great sense of responsibity" since there is no adjective in the main text @smatterer

Comment: Do you mean **due** respect?  I do not know what  a "gratitude certification" is.  A certificate of gratitude? A formal commendation of some kind?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo its an appreciation certificate https://goo.gl/SPT4K8  what does due respect mean? Its not a negetive content, Im looking for a formal phrase that presents respects for some one's great sense of responsibility

Comment: "with do [sic] respect" is not correct. **do** is a verb.  **due respect** means **the respect a person deserves or merits**.

Comment: Yes, certificate, not "certification". A certification attests that someone or something has met a particular standard, such as when a person passes an exam to be an accountant, or a restaurant's kitchen passes a cleanliness exam so that they are allowed to serve food to the public.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo so it doesn't have negetive meaning? Is it correct to say "with due respect to your great sense of honor" in a formal text?

Comment: You cay say *with all due respect* when you are going to disagree with someone or tell them they are wrong about something. I'm only using **due** because you seemed to be using the word when you wrote "with do respect". I would not use it in a commendation, since "due respect" does not mean "great respect", it means "the respect you deserve (but no more respect than that)".

Comment: To learn the formulaic phrases used in such certificates, you could search Google for "Certificate of Appreciation examples" or "Certificate of Commendation examples"

Comment: Normally we use the plural **respects** with a modifier, e.g "our respects". We attend a funeral to pay our respects.  The word **respects** is not really used in a certificate of appreciation or commendation.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I have searched it but i didnt find any matches for the sentence Im trying to translate. would you give me some suggestions? How about "respectfully presented for your great sense of responsibilty"?

Comment: "respectfully presented" (@smatterer 's suggestion above) is a good one. But "for your responsibility" might be better as "for your sense of responsibility" or "for your dedication to {some goal or principle}".

Comment: If you want a verb for "giving respect to" you could say "commending". The person to whom such a certificate is presented is "commended" for their commitment to a cause or for their generosity or sacrifice or other actions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use "With Respect" on a certificate as it would not only refer to someone has obtained/ received the award, but acknowledge them at the same time.

This can emphasis the words, which have a context of acknowledge.

Look at this sentence.

*With great Respect* I proudly announce this Award, to C.s Lewis, for his outstanding creativity for his Chronicles.

See how we are acknowledging the person, yet we giving them the award.

"With Respect" would be presenting the award in a distinguished way, making the person receiving the award, proud. That's the whole point of rewards right?

Therefore, Yes. We can say with respect, to whom we are presenting the Award to, which will have the same context as "I proudly present this award to..."

Answer (score 0):

The XYS Institute

**Extends its **heartfelt appreciation**** and gratitude to Ms. XXXX for all the care and responsibility she has shown in furthering our mission and work on behalf of [to come].

We would **not use the word respectful** here.